# Исправить коды \u в html-файлах (javadoc из NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, javadoc

Покопавшись в интернете нашёл причину кодов \u**** в html-файлах, получающихся при создании документации html из javadoc-комментариев, записанных в исходном коде файлов *.java:
[Unicode in javadoc and comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363188/unicode-in-javadoc-and-comments/10365243).

ПС: Попробовал через ant (из комплекта с netbeans - настроил Path в доп. параметрах Windows, "ant -version" показывает 1.9.7 от 09.04.2016) - не помогло... Цель из build.xml:

```
<target name="javadoc-build" description="documentation" depends="">
    <property name="app.name"    value="..." />
    <property name="app.version" value="1.0" />
    <property name="app.author"  value="Renat Khusyainov" />
    <property name="app.year"    value="2018" />
    <property name="dir.src"     value="./src" />
    <property name="dir.doc"     value="./dist/javadoc" />

    <echo message="Create doc." />
    <mkdir dir="${dir.doc}" />

    <javadoc destdir="${dir.doc}" 
             encoding="utf-8"
             docencoding="utf-8"
             charset="utf-8"
             use="true"
             private="true"
             author="${app.author}" 
             version="${app.version}" 
             windowtitle="${app.name} API"
             doctitle="${app.name}" >
        <fileset dir="${dir.src}" defaultexcludes="yes">
        </fileset>
    </javadoc>
</target>
```

ППС: "Убрать кириллицу из кода", которая "превращается" в юникод-символы, не вариант - считываемые данные (с которыми работает "проект") содержит кириллицу (и, соответственно, кириллица в коде помогает идентифицировать определённые участки считываемых данных). Закодировать кириллицу в коде - тоже не представляю возможным - "пострадает читабельность" кода.

Вот этот код из java-файла:

```
/**
 * Название параметра, по которому идентифицируется параметр {@value}.
 */
public static final String TIME_NAME = "Время сбора данных";
```

"превращается" вот в этот код html:

```
<td class="colLast"><code><span class="memberNameLink"><a href="../тут_путь__неважно.html#TIME_NAME">TIME_NAME</a></span></code>
<div class="block">Название параметра, по которому идентифицируется параметр "\u0412\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f \u0441\u0431\u043e\u0440\u0430 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0445".</div>
</td>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

В командной строке javadoc есть параметры [-charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#charset), [-encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#encoding) и [-docencoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#docencoding). См. [The Java API Documentation Generator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html). Всегда можно сгенерить документацию из командной строки вне зависимости от IDE. Не знаю что там не так в NetBeans, возможно зависит от кодировки ваших Java файлов, но, если вы не используете для сборки проекта maven, то попробуйте найти где-нибудь в project.properties что-нибудь вроде javadoc.encoding и исправить этот параметр.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но это "слишком глубоко" (не то, что я хотел)... Дополнил "ПС:"...

Comment: Уверен, что ваши java файлы сейчас в кодировке win-1251, настройте свою IDE таким образом, что бы java файлы создавались в кодировке utf-8. Уже созданные ранее файлы надо будет конвертировать.

Comment: Снова благодарю за ответ, Игорь, но, к сожалению, Ваша уверенность не оправдана. У меня было такое предположение, проверял (и сейчас ещё раз)... Akelpad показывает кодировку "65001 (UTF-8) без BOM", русские предложения читаются (не "иероглифы").

Comment: Командная строка не помогла. Может быть проблема в том, что я что-то не знаю про {@value}? У oracle не нашёл ответ, через google пока тоже...

Comment: Про {@value} есть в документации на которую я приводил ссылку выше [The Java API Documentation Generator. JAVADOC TAGS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#value), но скорее всего, это не поможет.